# How do you access private methods or attributes from outside the type they belong to?

Tags: metaprogramming, private, raku, rakudo

In some rare cases where this would actually be acceptable, like in unit tests, you may want to get or set the value of a private attribute, or call a private method of a type where it shouldn't be possible. Is it really impossible? If not, how can you do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways you can access a private method of a type, and one way to get private attributes. All require meta-programming except for the first way to invoke private methods, whose explanation still involves meta-programming anyway.

As an example, we will be implementing a `Hidden` class that hides a value using a private attribute, and a `Password` class that uses `Hidden` to store a password. **Do not copy this example to your own code. This is not how you would reasonably handle passwords; this is solely for example's sake.**

## Calling private methods

### Trusting other classes

`Metamodel::Trusting` is the meta-role that implements the behaviour needed for higher-order workings (types of types, or kinds, referred to from hereon out as HOWs) to be able to trust other types. `Metamodel::ClassHOW` (classes, and by extension, grammars) is the only HOW that's builtin to Rakudo that does this role.

`trusts` is a keyword that can be used from within packages to permit another package to call its private methods *(this does not include private attributes)*. For example, a rough implementation of a password container class could look like this using `trusts`:

```
class Password { ... }

class Hidden {
    trusts Password;

    has $!value;

    submethod BUILD(Hidden:D: :$!value) {}

    method new(Hidden:_: $value) {
        self.bless: :$value
    }

    method !dump(Hidden:D: --> Str:D) {
        $!value.perl
    }
}

class Password {
    has Hidden:_ $!value;

    submethod BUILD(Password:D: Hidden:D :$!value) {}

    method new(Password:_: Str:D $password) {
        my Hidden:D $value .= new: $password;
        self.bless: :$value
    }

    method !dump(Password:D: --> Str:D) {
        qc:to/END/;
        {self.^name}:
        $!value: {$!value!Hidden::dump}
        END
    }

    method say(Password:D: --> Nil) {
        say self!dump;
    }
}

my Password $insecure .= new: 'qwerty';
$insecure.say;

# OUTPUT:
# Password:
# $!value: "qwerty"
#
```

### Using the ^find_private_method meta-method

`Metamodel::PrivateMethodContainer` is a meta-role that implements the behaviour for HOWs that should be able to contain private methods. `Metamodel::MethodContainer` and `Metamodel::MultiMethodContainer` are the other meta-roles that implement the behaviour for methods, but those won't be discussed here. `Metamodel::ClassHOW` (classes, and by extension, grammars), `Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW` and `Metamodel::ConcreteRoleHOW` (roles), and `Metamodel::EnumHOW` (enums) are the HOWs builtin to Rakudo that do this role. One of `Metamodel::PrivateMethodContainer`'s methods is `find_private_method`, which takes an object and a method name as parameters and either returns `Mu` when none is found, or the `Method` instance representing the method you're looking up.

The password example can be rewritten not to use the `trusts` keyword by removing the line that makes `Hidden` trust `Password` and changing `Password!dump` to this:

```
method !dump(Password:D: --> Str:D) {
    my Method:D $dump = $!value.^find_private_method: 'dump';

    qc:to/END/;
    {self.^name}:
    $!value: {$dump($!value)}
    END
}
```

## Getting and setting private attributes

`Metamodel::AttributeContainer` is the meta-role that implements the behaviour for types that should contain attributes. Unlike with methods, this is the only meta-role needed to handle all types of attributes. Of the HOWs builtin to Rakudo, `Metamodel::ClassHOW` (classes, and by extension, grammars), `Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW` and `Metamodel::ConcreteRoleHOW` (roles), `Metamodel::EnumHOW` (enums), and `Metamodel::DefiniteHOW` (used internally as the value `self` is bound to in accessor methods for public attributes) do this role.

One of the meta-methods `Metamodel::AttributeContainer` adds to a HOW is `get_attribute_for_usage`, which given an object and an attribute name, throws if no attribute is found, otherwise returns the `Attribute` instance representing the attribute you're looking up.

`Attribute` is how attributes are stored internally by Rakudo. The two methods of `Attribute` we care about here are `get_value`, which takes an object that contains the `Attribute` instance and returns its value, and `set_value`, which takes an object that contains the `Attribute` instance and a value, and sets its value.

The password example can be rewritten so `Hidden` doesn't implement a `dump` private method like so:

```
class Hidden {
    has $!value;

    submethod BUILD(Hidden:D: :$!value) {}

    method new(Hidden:_: $value) {
        self.bless: :$value;
    }
}

class Password {
    has Hidden:_ $!value;

    submethod BUILD(Password:D: Hidden:D :$!value) {}

    method new(Password:_: Str:D $password) {
        my Hidden:D $value .= new: $password;
        self.bless: :$value
    }

    method !dump(Password:D: --> Str:D) {
        my Attribute:D $value-attr = $!value.^get_attribute_for_usage: '$!value';
        my Str:D       $password   = $value-attr.get_value: $!value;

        qc:to/END/;
        {self.^name}:
        $!value: {$password.perl}
        END
    }

    method say(Password:D: --> Nil) {
        say self!dump;
    }
}

my Password:D $secure .= new: 'APrettyLongPhrase,DifficultToCrack';
$secure.say;

# OUTPUT:
# Password:
# $!value: "APrettyLongPhrase,DifficultToCrack"
#
```

## F.A.Q.

### What does `{ ... }` do?

This stubs a package, allowing you to declare it before you actually define it.

### What does `qc:to/END/` do?

You've probably seen `q:to/END/` before, which allows you to write a multiline string. Adding `c` before `:to` allows closures to be embedded in the string.

### Why are grammars classes by extension?

Grammars use `Metamodel::GrammarHOW`, which is a subclass of `Metamodel::ClassHOW`.

### You say ^find_private_method and ^get_attribute_for_usage take an object as their first parameter, but you omit it in the example. Why?

Calling a meta-method on an object passes itself as the first parameter implicitly. If we were calling them directly on the object's HOW, we would be passing the object as the first parameter.

Comment: The first example you list outputs an error:
`Type check failed in binding to parameter '<anon>'; expected Password but got Hidden (Hidden.new)` on the `Password!dump` method on the line `$!value: {$!value!dump}`
Apparently it tries to call `Password!dump()` instead of `Hidden!dump()`.
I'm using perl6 v.2019.07.1

Comment: That appears to be a bug in Rakudo according to #perl6 https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6?date=2019-09-24#l400

Comment: The issue turned out to be a design choice rather than a bug. The example should work now.

Comment: Wait, why do you use :_ as type smiley? Will you use it for type objects too?

Comment: Good question @jjmerelo, my version is: Will you use it for object instances too?

Comment: @p6steve actually I meant the container designated by it. It didn't look as if it could be used for type objects...